# Prove that any left coset of $H$ in $G$ are either distinct (or disjoint) or equal.

Tags: group-theory

I was reading group theory from Topics in Algebra by I.N Herstein . There was relation defined :

> If $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ , then for $a,b\in G$, we define $a\equiv b\pmod{H}$ if $ab^{-1}\in H $ .

Now, this is an equivalence relation.  We know that every right coset of $H$ i.e $aH$(for $a\in H$) , we can say, $aH=[a]$(, where $[a] $ is the equivalence class of $a$ defined under the above relation ).

However, I was thinking if we could have the same for the left coset of $H$ as well . I did the a proof for it as as well and here goes it :

> If $a\in G $ then $aH$ is the left coset of $H$ in $G$. Then, if we define a relation $x\equiv a\pmod {H}$ such that ($a,x\in G$ ) , $x^{-1}a\in H$ . Now, we claim that this is an equivalence relation.
>
> 1. For any $a,b,c\in G$ we have $a\equiv a\pmod {H}$, then $a^{-1}.a=e\in H$ .
> 2. Also, if $b\equiv a\pmod {H}$ then we can say, $a\equiv b\pmod {H}$ as if $b^{-1}a\in H$ then $(b^{-1}a)^{-1}\in H$ , hence $a^{-1}b\in H$ , which means $a\equiv b\pmod {H}$.
> 3. If $a\equiv b\pmod {H}$, and $b\equiv c\pmod {H}$ then we can say $a\equiv c\pmod {H}$. This is because if $a^{-1}b\in H$ and $b^{-1}c\in H$ , then $a^{-1}bb^{-1}c\in H$ which means $a^{-1}c\in H$ and hence $a\equiv c\pmod {H}$.
> 4. Thus , we proved that the above relation is an equivalence relation.

> Now, we claim that $aH=[a]$(,where $[a]$ is the equivalence class of $a$ under the above relation). Now, we first prove that, $aH\subset [a]$. If $ah\in aH$ for $a\in G$ and $h\in H$. Then $(ah)^{-1}a=h^{-1}\in H$ and hence, $ah\in [a]$ . Hence,  we can say, $aH\subset [a]$. Now, we prove that $[a]\subset aH$. If $x\in [a]$ , then $x^{-1}a\in H$, which means  , $x^{-1}a\in H$ and hence $(x^{-1}a)^{-1}\in H$ . Thus, $a^{-1}x\in H$ and if $a^{-1}x =h$ for a $h\in H$ , then $x =ah$ and hence $x\in aH$. Thus, we can say, $[a]\subset aH$. So, we can say , $[a]= aH$. Hence, we can say, any left coset of $H$ in $G$ are either distinct (or disjoint) or equal.

Is the above proof valid? Does it hold true? If not, then where is it going wrong?...

Comment: Seems fine. The fundamental theorem of equivalence relations is also useful here since it simplifies the argument significantly.

Comment: I've always had trouble with right and left; but since there are two; maybe $aH$ and $Ha$, especially in Chicago :)

Comment: Let $a, b, h \in G $ such that $ab^{-1}=h$. Then $a=hb$ and $b=h^{-1}a;$ . So, $b\in Ha$.